# Android studio keeps reverting to an older copy of XML

Tags: android, xml, windows, android-studio, ide

I was making changes in one of the xml files in my Android Studio project on Windows 10 then this after clicking Ctrl + s by mistake, it never saves the current file and then I receive this error:

**Following errors occurred on attempt to save files: Cannot save blabla.xml. Unable to open the file for writing.**

This window keeps appearing prior to building:
[image: img1]

Comment: clear android studio cache and restart from file menu

Comment: @RohitKumar I did "File > Invalidate Caches / Restart" and there is still the same error.

Comment: open your project folder in window explorer, and check view hidden files, then delete your .idea folder if present

Comment: and make sure you open android studio as an administartor

Comment: @RohitKumar I opened the project files from the studio, how to exactly show hidden files? and in which directory do you mean?

Comment: which OS u are using?

Comment: @RohitKumar Windows 10 as mentioned above.

Comment: open My Compure -> navigate to your project folder -> on the top menu you will found view option -> then tick show hidden items

Comment: @RohitKumar Same problem still exist.

Comment: @MohammedFawaz what is the location of your android project on your computer ?? and are you using an admin account on windows ??

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo it is branching from Local Disk E. It was running perfectly until I clicked the Ctrl+s by mistake. 

and yes I am admin user on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy content of xml, save to place outside of android
   studio
2. Delete file from android studio
3. Create new file with same name
4. Copy saved content to new xml.

This fixed my problem invalidate/restart didn't worked.